# How to resize an .ai file in Photoshop CS4 without reducing image quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics, photoshop-cs4

Am I right to assume you can enlarge .ai files without reducing the image quality? Are these vector files?

Also, can you click & drag the object to make it bigger or do you have to use the resize tool where you put in dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import .ai files as Smart Objects that can be resized without any loss in quality by going to:

FILE (top menu) > PLACE

[image]

or on a Mac:

Photoshop (top menu) > PLACE

Yes, you can click and drag the object to make it bigger.